# Apache NiFi doesn't build when i run on the minishift for test-dev

Tags: linux, docker, openshift, apache-nifi, minishift

When i try to build the follows link according to DockerFile code on minishift, it doesnt work successfully. Any idea to fix ?

Link for DockerFile;

https://github.com/rromannissen/nifi-openshift/blob/master/base/Dockerfile

++Edited Dockerfile;

```
USER root
WORKDIR ${NIFI_HOME}
RUN chmod +x start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["../scripts/start.sh"]
```

Still doesnt build...

Error 1:

```
Removing intermediate container b4e143597109
Step 23/24 : RUN chmod +x start.sh
 ---> Running in c5ebd4bae255

    chmod: cannot access '/start.sh': No such file or directory
    Removing intermediate container e55eb176f952
    The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /start.sh' returned a non-zero code:1
```

Detailed Issue from Output:

```
    Removing intermediate container b4e143597109
    Step 23/24 : RUN chmod +x start.sh
     ---> Running in c5ebd4bae255
    
    chmod: cannot access 'start.sh': No such file or directory
    Removing intermediate container c5ebd4bae255
    The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x start.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
    keremceliker@kerems-mbp nifi %
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a chmod +x on that bash script you need to specify a correct path. I think for this Dockerfile is '../scripts/start.sh'. To identify the correct path you can run the Docker until that step and then enter it and identify what path is needed there.

Comment: As you said i changed the Dockerfile as i provided the follows link above  but im still experiencing that same issue. Could you or someone check github link accordng to Dockerfile for me ? That really would be great for sure ! - Kerem Çeliker

Comment: That link is not part of the official NiFi distribution and hasn't been updated in over 1 year. Try looking at the [current NiFi Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile) to see what changes, if any, need to be made.

Comment: Thanks Andy, i see as you said unfortunately i have tried it too =) yes, Its completely builted correctly but i got **different error as the follows below  ?**

`replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
sed: can't read /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I ve fixed that issue with Dockerfile after i changed the image set and add permisson with non-root user. Finally i did re-generate and re-build again on OpenShift, it works as Pods that NiFi and Zookeeper!